# Can't make an onClick with Zepto

Tags: javascript, zepto

Hello I have a simple HTML page like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test page</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.init([
          "param", "123456789"
        ]);
        app.execute();
        app.edit();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The content of `script.js` is the following:

```
// Zepto include
...

// My code
var app = app || (function(){
    var _args = {};

    return {
        init : function(Args) {
            _args = Args;
        },
        execute : function() {
            ...
        },
        edit: function() {

            $('body').on('click', function(e){ 
                alert('aa');
            });

        },
    };
}());
```

My problem is with this instruction `$('body').on('click', function(e){`.

I do not understand why.

It do not work.

Anyone to help me ?

Comment: It looks like other elements might be stopping event propagation up to the body. What does the rendered HTML output look like, in the form of a [mcve]?

Comment: When I click on the page, I expect an `alert`.

Comment: Yeah, but what does the page look like?

Comment: This is important because of the way event propagation works in HTML/Javascript. Other elements you click on, even though they're part of the body of the page, may steal the event and keep it from propagating up to the body element.

Comment: I edited my question with the page structure. I do not have anything actually except that.

Comment: Is this page running on a website? If so, then you should be able to load the page in a browser, and use the browser's View Source or View Generated Source tool to get the content that Zepto spits out. This is what's important to us.